How to correctly set the high-symmetry point path block when there are breakpoints in the recommended path?
I watched Dr. Mohan's tutorial video, and the settings he provided are as follows:
BandLinesScale ReciprocalLatticeVectors             
                
%block BandLines                
1   0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    GM
75  0.0000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000    X
60  0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000    M
100 0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    GM
125 0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.5000000000    R
75  0.0000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000    X/R
60  0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000    M
%endblock BandLines             
                


However, in the example with a breakpoint path he used, although the coordinates for 'R' are not specified at 'X/R,' 'R' is already part of the path, so its coordinates are naturally included. I’d like to know how to handle paths like those in the last image, where 'Y' after 'X/Y' does not appear separately (how to let SIESTA know the coordinates for 'Y'). How can I define the path in the block in such cases?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

+1. Welcome to our community.

First, you need to know the crystal symmetry your system has. Then you found its first Brillouin zone and they high symmetry points. Take a look at this answer.
